# Independent text in between aligned \eqnarray

Tags: equations, text

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{This text tells about one equation and this is equation 1} \\
(x+y)^2 &=& x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \\
\text{This text tells about one equation and this is equation 2} \\
(x-y)^2 &=& x^2 - 2xy + y^2
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Like the above what if one wants to keep all the equations within one page aligned and want to keep text in between without disturbing those alignments?

Answer (score 6):

First you should not use the `eqnarray` environment, because it yields bad spacing. Use the `align*` environment from `amsmath`,  and the `\intertext` command, or `\shortintertext` from package `mathtools` (which is a very useful extension of `amsmath`) if you want a tighter spacing between text and maths. Furthermore, the syntax of `align` is simpler:

```
......
\usepackage{mathtools}%% loads amsmath
......
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    \intertext{This text tells about one equation and this is equation 1} 
    (x+y)^2 &= x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \\
    \intertext{This text tells about one equation and this is equation 2} 
    (x-y)^2 &= x^2 - 2xy + y^2
    \end{align*}
......
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use shortintertext or intertext (ref 3.10, AMSmath documentation) with the align environment like Bernard said in his answer. As is evident in the example below, this will align the equations about the alignment tab character '&'. If, however, you wish to keep the equations centred, use intertext with the gather environment as in example 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{align}
    A_1&=N_0(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega'),\\
    A_2&=\phi(\lambda;\Omega')-\phi(\lambda;\Omega),\\
    \intertext{and}
    A_3&=\mathcal{N}(\lambda;\omega).
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

The output of this is
[image]

Example 2

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}\noindent
A sesquilinear form \( f \) on a vector space \( V \) is said to be positive if \( \forall x \in V \)
\begin{gather*}
    f(x,x) \geq 0\\
\shortintertext{and}\\
    f(x,x) = 0 \text{ if and only if } x = 0.
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Nice first answer, would it be possible to extend it into code that can be compiled please? Starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`, it helps with future readers if the examples can be compiled

Comment: @JamesT Thank you for pointing that out! Just did. Hope this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
 \begin{eqnarray*}
&&\hspace*{-63pt}\text{This text tells about one equation and this is equation 1} \\
(x+y)^2 &=& x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \\
&&\hspace*{-63pt}\text{This text tells about one equation and this is equation 2} \\
(x-y)^2 &=& x^2 - 2xy + y^2
\end{eqnarray*}
```